# How to revoke the Health App's permissions to Messages

Tags: permission, privacy, data, health.app

Under *Privacy -> Health* the App Messages is listed as an App accessing my Health data, and in the Health App, Massages is listed as a Source.

How do I revoke those permissions?

And is there a way to delete the Health App altogether?

Answer (score 1):

You can't delete the health.app without jail breaking as it isn't listed in the [list](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT208094) or delete able built in apps.

Open the Health app and tap the Sources tab.

Tap an app or device.

> [image]

Then you can disable it as a source.

Comment: There is no disable button on my health screen.

To me, it looks like this: https://matheplanet.com/matheplanet/nuke/html/uploads/b/48840_iphonehealth.jpg

When I click on Messages, it just shows a list of collected data. No option to disable.

Comment: Any idea why my screen looks different?

Comment: @Sofnalihg3 have you tried going Settings-> messages or click in messages in health and clicking privacy

Comment: Yes, I've tried both of that. Same screen, no ON/OFF switch

Comment: @Sofnalihg3 ok. Could you please post a photo of the message settings page and the page if you click on messages in the health app